# Nested wrapping functions

Tags: c

Suppose I have these functions:

```
void DUT(void){
   /* Something under test*/
}

void loop_wrapper(void (*func)()){
  for(int i = 0; i<5000; i++)
    func();
}

void time_wrapper(void (*func)()){
  clock_t start, end;
  double cpu_time_used;
  start = clock();

  func();

  end = clock();
  cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000;
  printf("Execution time %f ms\n", cpu_time_used);
}

int main(void){
  time_wrapper(DUT);
}
```

In the code, it would not be possible to wrap DUT with both wrappers. Such a call might look like `time_wrapper(loop_wrapper(DUT));`. This would be invalid because time_wrapper takes a pointer to a function with no arguments.

Is there a neat way to allow calling none, one, or more such wrappers in a nested fashion?

Comment: I was going to ask this question already considering macro wrappers and variable argument functions. My initial thoughts were that macro wrappers would be tricky to write to look and feel like functions in most cases, but this ended up being not as big an issue as anticipated. If you have another approach, feel free to answer.

Comment: C has no concept of "pointer to a particular invocation of a function with some particular set of arguments" (what other languages call closures, or lambdas).

Comment: @Lee I understand theoretically what you are referring to, but I do not understand what that would look like in code. Can you give an example of how to use that to solve this problem?

Comment: How can I show what it would look like in code when the concept itself does not exist in the language? If you want closures, pick another language.

Comment: Are you are saying there is a way to type-cast a function with void/unknown arguments?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Function-like macros can be used fairly cleanly to sidestep the argument problem:

```
#define loop_wrapper(func)    \
  for(int i = 0; i<5000; i++){func;}


#define time_wrapper(func) \
  clock_t start, end;      \
  double cpu_time_used;    \
  start = clock();         \
  func;                    \
  end = clock();           \
  cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000; \
  printf("Execution time %f ms\n", cpu_time_used);

int main(void){
  time_wrapper(loop_wrapper((DUT()));
}
```

The preprocessor output will condense down to one line. Should be a non issue as this output does not need to be read by humans.

```
clock_t start, end; double cpu_time_used; start = clock(); for(int i = 0; i<5000; i++){DUT();}; end = clock(); cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / ((clock_t) 1000000) * 1000; printf("Execution time %f ms\n", cpu_time_used);;
```